# Auto-reverting only renderable PDF buffers

Tags: pdf, pdf-tools, auto-revert-mode, global-auto-revert-mode

I'm using pdf-view mode and the global auto-revert mode with LaTeX and
latexmk.  This works fine, except that, a couple of times during the
compilation, the PDF is in a useless state and the PDF window shows raw
data.  I was wondering whether it is possible to detect these useless,
unrenderable, states and dispense with the automatic reversion when they
obtain.  That is to say, whether it is possible to have PDF buffers
reverted only when the PDF is renderable.

Comment: What mode do you use for LaTeX? If you use AUCTeX, you can stop using auto-revert-mode in the PDF buffers, and let AUCTeX refresh the pdfview buffer when compilation is finished.

Comment: @Omar, I use AUCTeX and org babel.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to do `make file.pdf && \mv file.pdf view-file.pdf` and keep `view-file.pdf` open (auto-reverting) in emacs. The mv operation is "instant" so you don't see any partial file.